# Add HTTPS with R Plumber API

Tags: r, ssl, https, digital-ocean, plumber

I just bought a domain and am trying to set up HTTPS redirection on my R Plumber API hosted on Digital Ocean. I made sure that the droplet IP is pointing to the domain and checked that it works. So currently I can access the plumber API over HTTP. I have an SSL Certificate on DO with my domain name. I tried using a Load Balancer but that didn’t work. Any guidance for how I would proceed?

I also tried using the “do_connect_https” function from the plumberDeploy package, but I keep getting the error “Error: Authentication with ssh server failed”

I would be happy to provide any more details if needed. Thank you in advance.

For context, my function looks like this:

do_configure_https(

droplet(123456789),

"mydomainname.com",

"myemail@gmail.com",

TRUE)

Comment: Have you validated your ssh keys match on your local machine and on DO? https://github.com/meztez/plumberDeploy#plumberdeploy.

Comment: I think so, but how would I double check that? @BrunoTremblay

Comment: Read the README, it tells you how.

Comment: The key needs to be on the droplet too. plumber_deploy will automatically add it for you if you used that and your DO keys were previously set.

Comment: Using analogies::key_create() and I got the message: "Error: SSH Key is already in use on your account" @BrunoTremblay

Comment: Could you validate that both the local key and your droplet key have a matching public key?